# Vertical shifts in Latex

Tags: vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}

\begin{document} \Large $\begin{aligned}&=mathbf{(\hspace{1pt}\underline{\phantom{x_{1}}}\hspace{1pt},\hspace{1pt}\underline{\phantom{x_{1}}}\hspace{1pt},\hspace{1pt}\underline{\phantom{x_{1}}}\hspace{1pt}\vspace{-10pt},\hspace{1pt}\ldots\hspace{1pt},\hspace{1pt}\underline{\phantom{x_{1}}}\hspace{1pt})}\\
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

How can I drop the commas and ldots in line with the underlining?

Comment: You could replace the commas by `\raisebox{-0.5ex}{,}`, say, and you do not need `tikz` here.

Comment: @Marmot, that was the trick I needed. Yes this is apart of a larger program showing that the number of subsets of a set containing n elements is 2^{n} by mapping each subset to an n-tuple.

Comment: I'd rather raise the lines

Answer (score 2):

We can replace the `\underline` with a `\rule`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\newcommand*{\myrule}{\, \rule{1em}{1pt}\,}
\begin{document} \Large 

$=(\myrule ,\myrule ,\ldots,\myrule)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather raise the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\placeholder}{%
  \mspace{1mu}%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\mspace{16mu}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$,$}%
  \rule[0.2\ht\tw@]{\wd\z@}{0.6\ht\tw@}%
  \endgroup
  \mspace{1mu}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$(\placeholder,\placeholder,\placeholder,\dots,\placeholder)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The rules are 60% of the height of the comma and raised 20% thereof, to avoid too big black bands; the total width is 18mu (one em in the symbol font), but the rule itself is 16mu wide to leave 1mu side bearing.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem may be that the underlining is quite low.  If you use a 1pt rule at the text depth, it looks decent to me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\mydepth}

\begin{document}
\Large
\settowidth{\mywidth}{$x_1$}
\settodepth{\mydepth}{$x_1$}

$\begin{aligned}
  &=\mathbf{(\hspace{1pt}\rule[-\mydepth]{\mywidth}{0.5pt}\hspace{1pt},
    \hspace{1pt}\rule[-\mydepth]{\mywidth}{0.5pt}\hspace{1pt},
    \hspace{1pt}\rule[-\mydepth]{\mywidth}{0.5pt}\hspace{1pt},
    \hspace{1pt}\ldots\hspace{1pt},
    \hspace{1pt}\rule[-\mydepth]{\mywidth}{0.5pt}\hspace{1pt})}\\
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]